# I have shadows of mordor in my xbox one, yet it doesnt even register the CD? How do i fix this?

Tags: xbox-one

I have the CD, but it will not read t it to install. I have tried restarting the system, which has not worked. The game is not even showing up as installed.

Comment: I would try a hard reset first.  turn it off, unplug it for about ten seconds, then turn it back on.  also, make sure you're hooked up to the internet.

Answer (score -1):

To get a better understanding of your question you really should explain more compared to... it doesnt work.

Can it read the disc?
If no the disc might be dirty,  the xbox lense or maybe the disc contains scratches or your drive is dead
If yes is there enough space on your hdd. Settings -> storage
Do other discs get read?
If no it more starts to seem like a drive failure
If yes it must be something on the disc or storage
Does it display any error messages?
This would help us alot more if the're any.

Answer (score -2):

Tilt your xbox up at a forty-five degree angle and then insert the disc.